# Block elements in android development

Tags: android

I am going through the tutorials at developer.android.com and they do not cover something I want to try.

In my XML file (LinearLayout) I have 3 elements, a textblock and 2 buttons.

I would like to have the TextBlock taking up all available width. IN HTML terms I would like it to be block.

Then underneath I would like the 2 buttons to be on the same line. In HTML terms I would like it to be inline.

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:
Create a linearlayout and add textview and another linearlayout with orientation horizontal within that the 2 buttons.

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/app_name" />

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can sort of do it in one linear layout, but it's not going to be very flexible.  You'd either want to use a relative layout and position the button below the text view or you can use two linear layouts (first is vertical orientation containing the textview and the second linear layout, that one is a horizontal linear layout containing the two buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Simple fixes:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <Button android:id = "@+id/thisbutton"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_toRightOf="thisbutton"
/>
```

That's the basic idea.
Look up all the features that are available in the layouts.  Because there are a lot, and they are quite flexible.